# Sub menu items not visible on hover

Tags: css

I created a sticky fixed footer on my site. Finally got it to be sort of what I need, however my sub menu items are not visible when you hover over the parent menu item. They are definitely there you can see the bottom item but the ones that go above the footer aren't visible.

You can see the page here: http://feltzdesignbuild.com/fdb-tester/

Can anyone help me get the sub-menu items to show on top of the content?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: I can see the sub-menu when hovering on the parent using chrome latest build... which browser are you using?

Comment: Say, is your footer supposed to be inside the header? That looks like an odd construction.

Comment: Mr. Lister - The footer inside the header is from the theme I didn't change any of that coding.

Comment: GibboK - Yes, I fixed the issue myself, I put a note in but other than that I don't see how I can set this as answered or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, had to remove the overflow: auto; from the CSS.